# Find lower-tail in hypergeom dist using scipy.stats

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I know that I can find the pvalues for the upper tail in the hypergeom distribution using the example in [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html) website, namely using the `sf`(`survival function`).

But how can I find the opposite? Lower-tail? Is there a name that I'm missing for the opposite of the `survival function`?

Comment: can you include a concise example so that we can quickly reproduce your situation and check our answers?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the inverse survival function, `isf()`.